# How can i change dateformat of webform submission

Tags: webforms, datetime

Is there a way where we could change the date format of the form submission? For Example in the Webform I have created there's no date picker in it. But when the web form is submitted by the user by default it comes in this format Sun mm/dd/yyyy but I want it dd/mm/yyyy (It is stored in Structure ->Websforms -->Submissions)How can i change the date format once the webform is submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but you may need edit the date time in the configuration of your website in /admin/config/regional/date-time

[image]